# Fetch mail into Gmail from external server more often than once per hour

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

Gmail's "check mail using POP3" feature only checks for mail every hour or so for me. I want the mail in my mail server to be forwarded to Gmail every few minutes.

What is the best way to set something up to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can always setup your account on the POP3 server to auto-forward e-mails to your Gmail account, which will have them show up almost instantly.

If maintaining a proper return address is important to you (Gmail vs. POP3), then you can go to your account settings and specify another account in the "Send Mail As" section that will allow you to use the POP3 return address on those e-mails that have been forwarded.

Comment: I didn't have access to the web server, but you reminded me that I could call my provider, and I got it all set up to forward. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Atomix if this answer your question, you're very welcomed in case you can simply "accept" it by clicking on the check mark! ;)